# How to configure my local Drupal site to contact my local Apache Solr server?

Tags: search

I installed Apache Solr server on my local machine and installed the [Apache Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module on my Drupal 7 site. When I configure the module and click submit an error message appears:

> Your site was unable to contact the Apache Solr server.

[image]

But when I go to http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ my Solr admin opens.

[image]

Comment: What if you try with http://127.0.0.1 instead of http://localhost

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added any cores to Solr and you need to add at least one core and adjust the connection properties.

You will probably need the Solr 7 config from [Search API Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr), as Apache Solr Search only has config for 5.x. The commands you need to run are: (replace CORE with the actual name)

1. `cd /opt/solr/server/solr`
2. `sudo mkdir -p CORE/conf`
3. `sudo cp -R search_api_solr/solr-conf/7.x/* CORE/conf`
4. `cd /opt/solr`
5. `sudo -u solr ./bin/solr create -c CORE -d server/solr/CORE/conf`

This should take the config files and create a core with those files. Then adjust your connection to http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE